# matplotlib error: x and y must have same first dimension and lambda function

Tags: python, matplotlib, lambda

I'm quite new to python and especially new to the lambda functions. I tried plotting the function that I define below, but I get

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (100,) and (1,)

From what I've seen of function plotting, I think the error is in the definition of my functions, i.e. W is badly defined.
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def W(t):
    s=lambda t: t
    for k in range(5):
        s=lambda t, y=s: y(t)+k
    return s
t=np.linspace(0,1,100)
plt.plot(t,W(t))
```

Comment: The error itself comes from `t` having 100 elements, while `W(t)` having a single element, namely the lambda function `s`. You would need to evaluate the function with some input. However once you do that you run into several other problems... I would recommend you start by creating a much simpler test case to understand the matter.

Comment: I understand that W(t) has only a single element. But why? W should be a function of t, as should s. Any help as to why s doesn't work as a function?

Comment: Yes `W` is a function of `t`. It returns a function, such that `W(t)` is a function of `t` as well. `W(t)(t)` might result in something else. But as said there are just so many problems in the code, at least I cannot solve them all without knowing what the final result should be.

Answer (score 0):

If I change my code to this, it works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def W(t):
    s=lambda x: x
    for k in range(5):
        s=lambda x, y=s: y(x)+k
    return s(t)
t=np.linspace(0,1,100)
plt.plot(t,W(t))
```